# Are votes for a question migrated together the question?

Tags: support, migration, voting

Suppose that a user with an account on both *Stack Overflow* and *Drupal Answers* ask a question on SO, which gets 5 votes, and which is then migrated to DA where it gets 5 votes further. Does the user account on DA gets 50 points for all the votes, or does it get only 25 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The votes are preserved on the destination site - they'll be cast by the Community user.

See [this MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges/6458#6458) for more details.